# Cocoa - Enumerate mutable array, removing objects

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, duplicates, enumerate

I have a mutable array that contains mutable dictionaries with strings for the keys latitude, longitude and id.  Some of the latitude and longitude values are the same and I want to remove the duplicates from the array so I only have one object per location.

I can enumerate my array and using a second enumeration review each object to find objects that have different ids, but the same latitude and longitude, but if I try to remove the object, I'm muting the array during enumeration.

Is there any way to remove objects from an array while enumerating so I only enumerate the current set of objects as the array is updated?

Hope this question makes sense.

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 5):

Count up an index variable as you enumerate. When you come upon a dictionary you're interested in removing, add its index to a [mutable index set](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/). Then, when you finish enumerating, send the array [a `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectsAtIndexes:), passing the index set.

The other way would be to build up a second array, then send the first array a `setArray:` message, passing the second array—or release the first, retain the second, and set the second as the new first.

On an unrelated note, you might consider replacing the dictionaries with [model objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/). It tends to make for cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I actually tried something like this, but there's a problem.

If I'm on index 3 and I find it has the same location as index 4, I would add index 4 to the array "to be removed".  When I loop around for the next iteration I want the object at index 4 to be skipped since I already know it's a duplicate.  

Is there any way to remove objects from the original array as I enumerate or by using some other looping method?

Comment: Ward, neither of the methods Peter suggests has the problem you describe. Nevertheless, there is a simple way to avoid it if you want to do things manually: iterate over the objects to be deleted from the highest index to the lowest.

Comment: Ward: No, you cannot mutate the array while you enumerate it. That will cause a Cocoa exception. You must either mutate it or replace it *after* the loop, or loop on a copy. I recommend the `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can. You need to go from top index to 0. 
Try this:

```
for (int i = [mutableArray count] -1; i >=0; i--) {
    id yourObject = [mutableArray objectAtIndex: i];
    BOOL needToDelete;
    // place you conditions here...

    if (needToDelete) {
        [mutableArray removeObject: yourObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i use reverseObjectEnumerator for it?

Comment: Yes, you can. I've just tested it with reverseObjectEnumerator and it works fine.